# Wix 3.5 Create Scheduled Task

Tags: .net-3.5, wix, scheduled-tasks, wix3.5

I've got a couple of projects I'm using Wix 3.5 for, along with Paraffin which is going really well, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to create a Windows Scheduled Task as part of the installation.

I could just run a bat file that creates the task, but I don't think that would give me the uninstall features that Wix has, nor allow me to define it as part of the setup UI.

Does anyone know how to create a scheduled task as part of the XML Configuration in Wix 3.5?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't avoid writing a custom action for this. Here's [the sample](https://www.trycatchfail.com/2008/07/28/wix-snippet-creating-a-scheduled-task/). Alternatively, you can wrap this functionality into [WiXExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extensions.htm) and e.g. "tie" it to a component, but that's far more work to be done.